# Changing database results in model as object

Tags: php, codeigniter

In past Codeigniter projects, I have always used `$query->result_array()` instead of `$query->result()`

For example, as an array, I would have the following in a model:

```
$this->db->select('id, username');
$this->db->from('users');

$query = $this->db->get();

$result = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    $id = $row['id'];

    $result[$id]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $result[$id]['username'] = strtolower($row['username']);

)

return $result;
```

It can get really messy with more records and I have to add all of the fields even if I just need to perform operations on only one of them.

Now, for my current project, I am trying to just `$query->result()`, which is just an array of objects, but I'm not sure how to perform operations on them and return the results.

For example, if I'm using `$query->result()` and I want to make every username lowercase (strtolower), how would I perform those changes in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your example and comment:

```
$results = $query->result();
    foreach($results as $result){
        $result->username = strtolower($result->username);
    }
return $results;
```

Comment: What would I return? `$query->result()`?

Comment: Well, actually you could store the $query->result() in a variable and then alter it. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($query->result() as $row){
    $username_lower = strtolower($row->username);

    //if you want to actually update the record in the db
    $this->db->where('id',$row->id);
    $this->db->update('users', array('username' => $row->username));
}
```